# Как мне добавить роль админа при создании пользователя?

Tags: vue.js, firebase

Я работаю над проектом. Нужно как-то сделать роль админа в firebase. Пользователь создается вот таким образом:

```
async createUser(context, { email, password, user}) {
  try {
    console.log('user', user)
    await firebase
      .auth()
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
    
    const userFirebase = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    userFirebase.updateProfile({
      displayName: user
    })

    setUserToState(context, user);

    /*              setUserToState(context, responce); */
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error', error)
    throw error.message;
  }
},
```

**Как мне добавить роль админа или может есть другой способ решить эту проблему ?**